# process json array object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to javascript(json) I want to process each json object,the example prototype is given below please help me to solve the problem,I need to console it each room number given in json sample below

how can I loop through the each item in json array so that I can get individual json element and console it on browser window

```
let data = [  
   { 
        "king" :[
                    {
                        "id" : 1,
                        "room_no" : 101,
                        "price" : 2000  
                    },
                    {
                        "id" : 2,
                        "room_no" : 102,
                        "price" : 3000  
                    },
                ] 
    }      
]
```

sorry for my bad english

Comment: There is no JSON in this question. That's a JavaScript object. JSON is a format, and is always a string.

Comment: And explain how you want to show it too.

Comment: JSON != JavaScript. What you have is a JavaScript object not a string of JSON formatted data.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
let data = [{
  "king": [{
      "id": 1,
      "room_no": 101,
      "price": 2000
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "room_no": 102,
      "price": 3000
    },
  ]
}]

data[0].king.forEach(item => console.log(item.room_no));
```

Comment: It does the job (well, not quite. It doesn't output the room number), but don't use `.map`. That's not its purpose. Use `.forEach`.

Comment: Here, I updated it.

Comment: Still using `.map` for no reason, though

Comment: Hey @JeremyThille. Thanks for the  upvote. I would have never gone and looked for the scenarios of foreach and map if you wouldn't have pointed out. So I just read a few posts on it. I guess one is always learning, thanks.